# Difference between libglfw3-dev in apt repository and glfw source code provided on github?

Tags: glfw

I am trying to get into graphics programming on ubuntu 20.04, and I'm trying to set up glfw for using OpenGL. I found two different ways of setting up glfw, one was using the apt repository and the other was compiling it using cmake. I just have one doubt, are both of these methods installing the same thing and if they differ then how? If both are same, then why doesn't the download page on GLFW state that?

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev
```

I tried searching the same question on the internet, didn't notice anything relatable. But I did notice in some tutorials that both installation included the same header file while coding

```
GLFW/glfw3.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that is an outdated version of GLFW.

According to [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libglfw3-dev), `libglfw3-dev` is GLFW 3.3.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. 3.3.2 was released 20.01.2020.

There are multiple [releases of GLFW on GitHub](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/releases), the newest one being 3.3.8, released 22.07.2022.

If you are building from source, you can pick which branch to build from. You can use [the stable 3.3 branch](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/tree/3.3-stable) to build from the most recent GLFW 3.3 (3.3.9 at the time of writing). Or, you can build from [GLFW's master branch](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/tree/master), which is the stable development branch of GLFW, and contains the additions to GLFW 3.4 that have been finalized. The master branch is stable enough for most projects to build from.

> I did notice in some tutorials that both installation included the same header file while coding
>
> ```
> GLFW/glfw3.h
> ```

That is the GLFW 3 include header. It's the same one for every version of GLFW 3.